# Error when compiling for Android (Native) Cocos2d-x

Tags: java, android, linux, cocos2d-iphone, android-ndk

Hi guys I am using linux operating system and when I try to compile the code for android ndk I get the below error.

What could be the reason?

```
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:688:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jlong _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualLongMethodA(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:688:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jfloat _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualFloatMethod(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:689:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jfloat _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualFloatMethodV(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:689:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jfloat _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualFloatMethodA(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:689:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jdouble _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualDoubleMethod(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:690:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jdouble _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualDoubleMethodV(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:690:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jdouble _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualDoubleMethodA(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:690:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualVoidMethod(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:697:78: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualVoidMethodV(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:702:76: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::CallNonvirtualVoidMethodA(jobject, jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:705:76: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function '_jfieldID* _JNIEnv::GetFieldID(jclass, char const*, char const*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:708:58: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function '_jobject* _JNIEnv::GetObjectField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:711:58: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jboolean _JNIEnv::GetBooleanField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:713:59: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jbyte _JNIEnv::GetByteField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:715:56: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jchar _JNIEnv::GetCharField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:717:56: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jshort _JNIEnv::GetShortField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:719:57: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jint _JNIEnv::GetIntField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:721:55: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jlong _JNIEnv::GetLongField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:723:56: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jfloat _JNIEnv::GetFloatField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:725:57: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jdouble _JNIEnv::GetDoubleField(jobject, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:727:58: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetObjectField(jobject, jfieldID, jobject)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:730:58: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetBooleanField(jobject, jfieldID, jboolean)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:732:59: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetByteField(jobject, jfieldID, jbyte)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:734:56: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetCharField(jobject, jfieldID, jchar)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:736:56: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetShortField(jobject, jfieldID, jshort)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:738:57: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetIntField(jobject, jfieldID, jint)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:740:55: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetLongField(jobject, jfieldID, jlong)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:742:56: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetFloatField(jobject, jfieldID, jfloat)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:744:57: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::SetDoubleField(jobject, jfieldID, jdouble)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:746:58: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function '_jmethodID* _JNIEnv::GetStaticMethodID(jclass, char const*, char const*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:749:65: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function '_jobject* _JNIEnv::CallStaticObjectMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:779:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function '_jobject* _JNIEnv::CallStaticObjectMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:779:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function '_jobject* _JNIEnv::CallStaticObjectMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:779:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jboolean _JNIEnv::CallStaticBooleanMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:780:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jboolean _JNIEnv::CallStaticBooleanMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:780:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jboolean _JNIEnv::CallStaticBooleanMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:780:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jbyte _JNIEnv::CallStaticByteMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:781:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jbyte _JNIEnv::CallStaticByteMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:781:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jbyte _JNIEnv::CallStaticByteMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:781:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jchar _JNIEnv::CallStaticCharMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:782:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jchar _JNIEnv::CallStaticCharMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:782:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jchar _JNIEnv::CallStaticCharMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:782:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jshort _JNIEnv::CallStaticShortMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:783:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jshort _JNIEnv::CallStaticShortMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:783:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jshort _JNIEnv::CallStaticShortMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:783:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jint _JNIEnv::CallStaticIntMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:784:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jint _JNIEnv::CallStaticIntMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:784:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jint _JNIEnv::CallStaticIntMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:784:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jlong _JNIEnv::CallStaticLongMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:785:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jlong _JNIEnv::CallStaticLongMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:785:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jlong _JNIEnv::CallStaticLongMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:785:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jfloat _JNIEnv::CallStaticFloatMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:786:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jfloat _JNIEnv::CallStaticFloatMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:786:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jfloat _JNIEnv::CallStaticFloatMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:786:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jdouble _JNIEnv::CallStaticDoubleMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:787:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jdouble _JNIEnv::CallStaticDoubleMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:787:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jdouble _JNIEnv::CallStaticDoubleMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:787:5: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(jclass, jmethodID, ...)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:793:69: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethodV(jclass, jmethodID, va_list)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:797:67: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'void _JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethodA(jclass, jmethodID, jvalue*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:799:67: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function '_jfieldID* _JNIEnv::GetStaticFieldID(jclass, char const*, char const*)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:802:64: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function '_jobject* _JNIEnv::GetStaticObjectField(jclass, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:805:66: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jboolean _JNIEnv::GetStaticBooleanField(jclass, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:807:67: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jbyte _JNIEnv::GetStaticByteField(jclass, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:809:64: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jchar _JNIEnv::GetStaticCharField(jclass, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:811:64: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jshort _JNIEnv::GetStaticShortField(jclass, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:813:65: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h: In member function 'jint _JNIEnv::GetStaticIntField(jclass, jfieldID)':
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:815:63: error: cannot convert '_JNIEnv* const' to 'JNIEnv* {aka JNIEnv_*}' in argument passing
/home/jessy/workspace2/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:
```